# jQuery content rotator

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, rotation, autorotate

Can someone recommend me some jQuery plugin, for the rotating this HTML structure.

```
<div id="event_rotator">
 <div class="event">
 <h2>Title</h2>
 <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="event">
 <h2>Title</h2>
 <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="event">
 <h2>Title</h2>
 <p>Text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like, that it would rotate the  automatically in the certain time period, when the user is on the page, and also that user can rotate it left and right with a click on an arrow.

I tried to use this http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager11.html , but I cannot get it to work.

The problem is, that I get this HTML dynamically, out of a PHP code.. I don't know, how to assign the needed css (I can assign that which is the same for all, but I cannot assign different Z-index.

Comment: S.O. is **not** a links suggestion site. Show us what have you tried and if you have an issue we'll be really happy to help you

Comment: I tried this http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ , but since it has not the ability to auto rotate is useless for me

Comment: well, than create your own, and if you got stuck in the code post it here and we'll take a closer look. And btw here on S.O. you have tons of sliders with buttons and all, with autoslides and everything. you just have to search more! If you have time I built already a couple. take a look at my answers for galleries-sliders

Comment: What do you mean by autorotate? Show a snaspshot.

Comment: On the contrary, jQuery Cycle automatically transitions by default. See the `timeout` option in the [option reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)

Comment: oh, thanks, so I only need the left and right arrows.. I think I will need to come back. Thanks for now!

Comment: Such arrows can be easily achieved by the `next` and `prev` commands. See the above reference for that as well. Also, take a look at [this demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager11.html).

Comment: The problem is, that I get this HTML dynamically, out of a PHP code.. I don't know, how to assign the needed css (I can assign that which is the same for all, but I cannot assign different Z-index. Help please?

Comment: Better edit your original question and add relevant information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created this in 10 min, so it's not a designer's gallery, but this one has all you need to **use** and **LEARN** how to create **your self** a slide gallery with left/right buttons, auto-rotate and hover/pause.

The HTML,CSS,JS code is really simple so take a look:

http://jsbin.com/ofukaq/8/edit

HTML:

```
<div id="event_rotator">

  <button id="left">left</button>
  <button id="right">right</button>  

  <div id="slider">
   
     <div class="event">
     <h2>Title1</h2>
     <p>Text1</p>
     </div>
     <div class="event">
     <h2>Title2</h2>
     <p>Text2</p>
     </div>
     <div class="event">
     <h2>Title3</h2>
     <p>Text3</p>
     </div>
   
  </div>
  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#event_rotator{
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slider{
  position:absolute;
  height:150px;
  left:0; 
  width:99999px;
}
.event{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  background:#eee;
}
```

and finally jQuery:

```
$(function(){

var W = $('#event_rotator').width();      // Gallery Width
var N = $('#slider .event').length;    // Number of elements
var C = 0;                          // Counter
var intv;                         // Auto anim. Interval


if(N<=1){ 
  $('#left, #right').hide();  // hide buttons only 1 element
}  


$('#slider').width( W*N );          // Set slider width

$('#left, #right').click(function(){
  // Animation logic
  if(this.id=='right'){
    
    C++;
    C = C % N;     // reset to '0' if end reached
    
  }else{ // left was clicked
    
    C--;
    if(C===-1){   // IF C turns -1 scroll to last one (N-1)
      C = N-1; 
    }
    
  }
  // Animation
  $('#slider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 1000 );
});


// auto rotate

function autoRotate(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
      $('#right').click();
  },2000); // pause time
}
autoRotate(); // start auto rotate

// pause hover

$('#event_rotator').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
   var mEnt = e.type=='mouseenter';
  if(mEnt){
     clearInterval(intv);
  }else{
     autoRotate();
  }
});

}); // * end document ready.
```

Hope I opened your eyes that sometimes you don't need a 3000 lines plugin to build a nice gallery with all the functionality you need.

---

Here is with a bit compressed jQuery script using **Ternary operators**:

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ofukaq/378/edit)

```
var W = $('#event_rotator').width(),
    N = $('#slider .event').length,
    C = 0,
    intv;

if(N<=1)$('#left, #right').hide(); 
$('#slider').width( W*N );

$('#left, #right').click(function(){
     C = (this.id=='right'? ++C : --C) < 0 ? N-1 : C%N ;
     $('#slider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 700 );
});

function auto(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
      $('#right').click();
  }, 3000 );
}
auto();

$('#event_rotator').hover(function( e ){
  return e.type=='mouseenter' ? clearInterval(intv) : auto();
});
```

Comment: working like a charm! All I need is to set the variables, so it will be more smooth. The buttons left/right are not working well, but I think that I will be able to set the variables that they will work ok

Comment: @MP If you did not noticed I edited my answer and added a better code. Logically the buttons were not working well cause in the old demo i placed them (HTML) **OUTSIDE** the gallery hover parent.

Comment: One more question, how to hide left/right buttons if there is only one <div class="event"> ?

Comment: @MP you see in jQUery the `var N = ` it returns the number of elements. just place after your vars: `if(N<=1){ $('#left, #right').hide(); }`

Comment: jQuery is magic :) I just see now, that we are neighbors, "puno ti hvala!"

Comment: @MP always nice to see neighbors around here! Nema na čemu! ;)

Comment: Seems like I am not able to position the buttons as I want (a little outside the box) if I do not set them before the <div id="event_rotator">. If I put them there, the slider is not working correctly. How could I fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: @MP let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22266/discussion-between-roxon-and-m-p)

Comment: marvelous solution!!! finally find plugin which works with object tag!!! + it is simple!

Comment: @chao thanks! :) just, actually it's not a plugin, just a simple code to handle one gallery (or more, if you tweak the code or transform it into a jQuery plugin).

Answer (score -1):

http://jsbin.com/ofukaq/8/edit

How to make this to loop shown titles like:

`Title 1 -> Title 2 -> Title 3 -> Title 1 -> title 2 ->` infinity loop

Instead of

```
Title 1 -> Title 2 -> Title 3
```

?